# Display the same time count but both components simultaneously

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I display the same time count in both places simultaneously as shown in the image?

I tried to pass the user ID of the component app to the navbar so that I could then use the function to get the timer, but to no avail.

Can anyone help me?

**HTML**

```
<p>NavBar</p>
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
    <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
        <img *ngIf="taskService.getCurrentState() === 'pause' || taskService.getCurrentState() === undefined" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcW6cJlI-KlS721hkuHDTMydZ_snrkhL9sm9wYHWRhd3FlvF1b&s" width="50" height="50">
        <img *ngIf="taskService.getCurrentState() ==='start'"
        src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg" width="50" height="50">
      </button>
    <div class="timer"  *ngIf="taskService.getCurrentState() === 'start'" >
        <!-- <span>{{(taskService.timerForUsers[idu].currentTime * 1000) | date:'HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}</span> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since taskService is a singleton service it will be easy to retrieve the information in many components. you could add a property in taskService to store the currentUserId. And then add a getter function to retrieve the time for the currentUserId. Navbar needs to inject the taskService as well and can access then the time of the currentUser

Comment: @spierala 
I tried to do what I said but I didn't inject correctly, I don't know what I did wrong :(

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the post itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: What do you mean with "I didn't inject correctly''. Do you see errors? 
Somehow here your stackblitz is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have taskService holding the time so you can just use that in the NavBar.
If you need to pass a specific user then use @Input() decorator to do so.

in navbar change userId to be input, and add code to show time:

```js
@Input() userId:string;
```

```html
<span>{{(taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID].currentTime * 1000) | date:'HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}</span>
```

then in your appComponent bind the Id to the userID input:

```html
<app-navbar  [userId]="data[0].ID"></app-navbar>
```

***Updated link to show multiple users***

I have edited your example to show it in action:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9knpqb
However: you need to clean up you data model a bit.

you can show multiple users instead by using a property to store the current user to show:

in app component, add the property and event to handle user change:

```js
currData: string;

rowClicked(event: any): void {
    this.currData = event.data.ID;
    console.log(this.currData);
  }
```

in the html change the binding to navbar and add event on the data grid:

```html
<app-navbar  [userId]="currData"></app-navbar>


<dx-data-grid  [dataSource]="data" height="600" showBorders="true" (onRowClick)="rowClicked($event)">
```

***EDIT: Store User ID for global access***

current user id can be stored in the TaskService if it is needed globally using a ***BehaviourSubject*** this can then be subscribed to in other components as shown in the updated example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqoaaf

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I think you posted the wrong link, this is the same as the post

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the post itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: This works, but if you have more than one user, it won't work anymore, as the date [0] refers only to the first :(

Comment: @MikeLanders instead of data[0] you can have something like currentData and then set currentData to the desired data.
e.g you can have each row use the DevExtreme onClick event to change to the clicked element.

Comment: @ChiragPatel perfect thank you. Is there a way to work this out but without passing data through input in the navbar?

Comment: @MikeLanders you'll have to give me a clearer understanding of what you want to achieve, but maybe yes.

Comment: @ChiragPatel 
Your solution worked well, my problem is that I need to use this value in the service so that it works on all pages if you want to change it (example: I'm in the home component and I move to the file component)

Comment: @MikeLanders when you say this value, are you referring to the selected user or the time?
If user then you can create a ***BehaviourSubject*** that can keep track of the current selected user in the Task Service.
If time, then you are already holding it in the Task Service.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I´m referring to the selected user

Comment: add a ***BehaviourSubject*** to the Task Service and then change it to the current user on the `rowClicked` function. see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqoaaf

Comment: Fantastic work, thank you very much. The only problem is that when I open the page, the button is already counting time, when it should only do it when it is clicked. Thank you very much !

Comment: np, timer already running is due to you saving items in LocalStorage, unless you need items to persist between sessions on the client end i would suggest retrieving the data from a API/server call.

Other option is to use `ngOnDestroy` in your service and make sure all timers are stopped when the app/page closes.